# Google Cloud Storage Avro to Cloud Spanner Dataflow Pipeline Throughput bottlenecked troubleshooting

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, avro, google-cloud-spanner

I've successfully made backups of a large database (> 1TB) and am trying to restore them using the `gcs_avro_to_cloud_spanner` dataflow template following the docs.

While it works, it is taking hours, with minimal throughput and using minimal resources.

How can I improve the throughput of the dataflow process, and the speed of the backup restore?

### Specifics

- **Cloud spanner** has 5000 processing units, CPU utilisation is 75% (all priorities), 8% (high priority).
- Throughput is ~20 MiB/s, with ~200 write operations per second.

- **Dataflow** is running on 10 `n2-highmem-2` workers (20 vCPUs)
- Throughput is ~50k elements/s or ~200 MiB/s
- CPU utilisation ~18%
- Memory utilisation ~54GB of 156GB available
- HDD PDs are limited to only 25GB per worker, but I don't think this can be configured any higher.

There are clearly resources available for a much higher throughput than 20MB/s, but it appears there is a bottleneck preventing them from being used. Any help of advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest contacting Google's sales for what appropriate resources are needed to your use case or create a support case for this: https://cloud.google.com/contact

Comment: Who are the owners of the other priority tasks? Are they system level tasks? Do you have any secondary indices? I've gotten ~ 6 MiB/s write throughput on a node with 900 compute units with most of the CPU utilization going to the writes. Your operations/s seem low though - my node with 500 compute units does ~150 operations/s 24/7 with semi-regular bursts up to 200 operations/s.
If you're writing a large amount of data, are you sorting your keys lexicographically and committing them in batches w/ less than 40k mutations/batch?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yeah we regularly see a similar load to what you describe and have no issues. Large insert jobs also work with a much higher throughput. This issue is specifically around the dataflow import template - I think indexes should not be relevant as the template runs on a fresh DB and creates indexes once the data is imported. Anything to do with sorting/ batching would be internal to the dataflow template I believe, which we don't have control of.